# Why is getenv('REMOTE_ADDR') giving me a blank IP address?

Tags: php, ip-address

This PHP code...

```
207    if (getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR)) {
208        $ip   = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR');
209        $host = gethostbyaddr($ip);
210    } else {
211        $ip   = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
212        $host = gethostbyaddr($ip);
213    }
```

Throws this warning...

> **Warning:** gethostbyaddr()
>   [function.gethostbyaddr]: Address is
>   not in a.b.c.d form in **C:\inetpub...\filename.php** on line **212**

It seems that *$ip* is blank.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

on php.net it says the following:

> The function `getenv` does not work if your Server API is ASAPI (IIS).
>   So, try to don't use `getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')`, but `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`.

Did you maybe try to do it with `$_SERVER`?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

and

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
```

Answer (score 2):

A better solution has already been given. But still:

```
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR');
```

should be

```
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
```

Yeah... sometimes computers want to have strings they understand ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, getenv() takes a string as parameter. On line 207, you should use:

```
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
```

...instead of:

```
getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR)
```

Secondly, accessing these variables through $_SERVER is a more reliable solution, as getenv() tends to display different behaviour on different platforms.

Also, these variables will probably not work if you are running this script through CLI.

Try a var_dump($ip); and see what the variable contains.